# Is there any keyboard shortcut to select/copy the auto highlighted text in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When I place my cursor at any position inside a text like the string in this photo, vs code automatically mildly highlights the entire string. Is there any shortcut key for selecting and copying this entire text highlighted by vs code?
[Example: String being mildly highlighted by vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqJSh.png) How to select/copy this with a keyboard shortcut?

Update:
Added gif to show the highlighting - [gif showing the highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTMz2.gif)

Comment: @Mark if the string comprises of more than one word, it does not select the entire string but only the word on which the cursor is placed.

Comment: @Mark No I do not have anything in the Find Widget and I think my VS code is default with no modifications for this to happen. I have updated my question with a gif for clarification.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I answered it below.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for taking time to help on my question. Will upvote your answer when I get enough reputation to upvote answers : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a single, builtin keyboard shortcut for the behavior you described, but you can use a combination of two to achieve the result you want:

The first is called "Expand Selection" in the VS Code app, and [the online keybindings documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#:%7E:text=editor.action.smartSelect.expand) describes it as "Expand AST Selection" (`editor.action.smartSelect.expand`). The default platform keybindings for this are:

- linux: shift + alt + right
- mac: shift + ctrl + cmd + right
- win: shift + alt + right

If the highlighted string is one word, it will require one use, and if the string is multi-word, it will require two uses.

After that, the selection will be complete, and you can simply copy (cmd/ctrl + c).

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If in a string, triggering the command `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` a couple of times should select that entire string.  And then you can copy the normal way Ctrl+C.

That command is unbound by default.  You can assign a keybinding to it in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` editor by searching for `smartSelect` and click on the little pencil icon next to the command.